# Want to generate 100 samples and label each sample as 0 or 1 based on a coin flip R

Tags: r, classification, logistic-regression, sampling, coin-flipping

I want to generate a 100 samples and then assign each sample a label of either a 0 or 1 based on a randomized coin flip. So if I flip heads, then I assign the sample a 0 and for tails I would assign the sample a 1.

So far I have:

```
n = 100
for (ii in 1:n){
  sample(n)[ii] #access one sample at a time 
}
```

But I am not exactly sure how I can apply the coin flip aspect to be assigned to each sample.

Comment: The code is probably not what you want, see what, say, `sample(5)` gives (a permutation of the integers `1:5`). Then you take the `ii`th element of each of n such permutations. To sample n binary values, use `rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.5)`.

Comment: Do you want `cbind(sample(n), rbinom(n, 1, prob = 0.5))`?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the data format of your desired ouput. This solution uses a data frame that puts each sample in one row and adds a `label` column to contain the random 0/1.

Change `n` to 100 instead of 5 to get your result.

```r
n <- 5
# Create n samples; result is matrix m with each row being one sample
m <- t(sapply(rep(n, n), sample))
# Convert to data frame - obviously
df <- as.data.frame(m)
# identify samples
rownames(df) <- paste0("sample", 1:n)
# add a name column to df that contains a 0/1 random variable
df$label <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)
df
#>         V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 label
#> sample1  2  4  5  1  3     0
#> sample2  3  2  1  5  4     1
#> sample3  4  2  1  5  3     0
#> sample4  2  1  5  3  4     0
#> sample5  3  4  2  1  5     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>